# I want to link each cell with different URL

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView and when the user click the cell, each cell should open a different URL
[image]

Here's the Code:

```
var mathLessons = [["1"],["2"],["3"],["4"]]

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
cell.textLabel?.text = lessons.mathLessons[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return cell
}
```

Comment: That should be very easy to do, did you try it? show code for `didSelectRowAt`

Comment: based on indexPath you can open different URL on didSelect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a custom struct which holds the lesson number and the corresponding URL

```
struct Lesson {
    let number : String
    let url : URL
}

var mathLessons = [Lesson(number: "1", url: URL(string:"https://...1")!), 
                   Lesson(number: "2", url: URL(string:"https://...2")!), 
                   Lesson(number: "3", url: URL(string:"https://...3")!), 
                   Lesson(number: "4", url: URL(string:"https://...4")!)]
```

in `cellForRow` show the number

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    cell.textLabel?.text = lessons.mathLessons[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].number
    return cell
}
```

in `didSelect` open the corresponding URL

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let url = lessons.mathLessons[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].url
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```

Comment: Thank you vadian, but xCode is crashing in this line : `cell.textLabel?.text = lessons.mathLessons[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].number // <-- CRASH: Type 'Lesson' has no subscript members`

Comment: Yes, of course. You have to adjust the code that the `Lesson` array fits your data source model (which I have no idea about)

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean by adjust the code that the Lesson array fits your data source model, Can you show me any example?

Comment: Can you show me the precise type of `lessons` (`lessons` is the data source model)?

Comment: I have two viewControllers the first one is:
    `class LessonsArray: UIViewController {
    var mathLessons = [Lesson(url: URL(string:"https://……”)!, title: "1"),
                       Lesson(url: URL(string:"https://……”)!, title: "2"),
                       Lesson(url: URL(string:"https:/…..”.)!, title: "3"),
                       Lesson(url: URL(string:"https://……”)!, title: "4")]
}
struct Lesson {
    var url : URL
    var title : String
}`
The second:
`class LessonsVC: UITableViewController {
let lessons = LessonsArray()
//….
}`

Comment: Your syntax cannot work. You cannot use an instance of an `UIViewController` as data source model. `LessonsArray()` creates a brand new instance which is **not** the instance in the storyboard. Reconsider your design.

Comment: What I have to write instead of UIViewController?

Comment: For a table view with sections you need a nested array. The outer array contains the **section** data and each section has an (inner) array which contains the **rows**

Comment: Thank you very much Vadian.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the delegate of `UITableView's didSelectRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // create url from string
   if let url = URL(string: mathLessons[indexPath.row]) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

change `mathLessons[indexPath.row]` with your `url` variable